# SELECT from table where id is not represented with another user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id id_imported_urls user_id
25041   23965   4
25040   23964   4
25039   23963   4
25037   23961   4
25034   23958   4
25033   23957   21
25032   23956   21
25031   23955   21
25030   23954   21
25029   23953   21
```

I'm trying to select rows, where the id_imported_urls is only present on the current user, but i cant figure out how to make the SQL call properly.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM links 
 WHERE id_imported_urls = 23965 
   AND user_id = 4
HAVING COUNT(SELECT * FROM links WHERE id_imported_urls = 23965) < 2
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: To get rows where id_imported_urls is only present with one user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT l.* FROM links l
WHERE l.id_imported_urls = 23965 AND l.user_id = 4
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM links
  WHERE user_id <> l.user_id AND id_imported_urls = l.id_imported_urls 
)
```

This will return a row only if `id_imported_urls = 23965` does not exist for any `user_id <> 4` .
This query:

```
select id_imported_urls
from links
group by id_imported_urls
having count(distinct user_id) = 1
```

returns all the `id_imported_urls` that belong to only 1 user, so you can use it like this:

```
select * from links
where id_imported_urls in (
  select id_imported_urls
  from links
  group by id_imported_urls
  having count(distinct user_id) = 1
)
```

to get all the rows that contain these `id_imported_urls`.

Comment: hmm, i have the listet table, but want all rows with user_id, and not any of the id_imported_urls is present with another user_id. So i did wrong in adding the WHERE id_imported_urls = 23965 in the first select.

Comment: See my edited answer if the last query solves your problem.